# XSLT- nested object using for-each element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to convert XML one format to another format using xslt transformation. But the problem is I don't know how to loop through the nested objects using for-each element.

XML Input format:

```
<SecrviceRsp>
<Application>
    <ApplicationName>Application-1</ApplicationName>
    <Parent>
        <ParentName>Parent-1</ParentName>
        <Service>
            <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
        </Service>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentName>Parent-2</ParentName>
        <Service>
            <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
            <ChildService>
                <ChildServiceName>Child Service-1</ChildServiceName>
            </ChildService>
            <ChildService>
                <ChildServiceName>Child Service-2</ChildServiceName>
            </ChildService>
            <ChildService>
                <ChildServiceName>Child Service-3</ChildServiceName>
            </ChildService>
        </Service>
        <Service>
            <ServiceName>Service-2</ServiceName>
        </Service>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentName>Parent-3</ParentName>
        <Service>
            <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
            <ChildService>
                <ChildServiceName>Child Service-1</ChildServiceName>
            </ChildService>
        </Service>
    </Parent>
</Application>
<Application>
    <ApplicationName>Application-2</ApplicationName>
    <Parent>
        <ParentName>Parent-5</ParentName>
        <Service>
            <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
        </Service>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentName>Parent-6</ParentName>
        <Service>
            <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
            <ChildService>
                <ChildServiceName>Child Service-1</ChildServiceName>
            </ChildService>
            <ChildService>
                <ChildServiceName>Child Service-2</ChildServiceName>
            </ChildService>
            <ChildService>
                <ChildServiceName>Child Service-3</ChildServiceName>
            </ChildService>
        </Service>
    </Parent>
    <Parent>
        <ParentName>Parent-7</ParentName>
        <Service>
            <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
            <ChildService>
                <ChildServiceName>Child Service-1</ChildServiceName>
            </ChildService>
        </Service>
    </Parent>
</Application>
```

XML Output format:

```
<ParentService>
<ParentName>Parent-1</ParentName>
<ServiceInfo>
        <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
    </ServiceInfo>
</ParentService>
<ParentService>
    <ParentName>Parent-2</ParentName>
    <ServiceInfo>
        <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
        <ChildServiceName>Child Service-1</ChildServiceName>
        <ChildServiceName>Child Service-2</ChildServiceName>
        <ChildServiceName>Child Service-3</ChildServiceName>
    </ServiceInfo>
    <ServiceInfo>
        <ServiceName>Service-2</ServiceName>
    </ServiceInfo>
</ParentService>
<ParentService>
    <ParentName>Parent-3</ParentName>
    <ServiceInfo>
        <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
        <ChildServiceName>Child Service-1</ChildServiceName>
    </ServiceInfo>
</ParentService>
<ParentService>
    <ParentName>Parent-5</ParentName>
    <ServiceInfo>
        <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
    </ServiceInfo>
</ParentService>
<ParentService>
    <ParentName>Parent-6</ParentName>
    <ServiceInfo>
        <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
        <ChildServiceName>Child Service-1</ChildServiceName>
        <ChildServiceName>Child Service-2</ChildServiceName>
        <ChildServiceName>Child Service-3</ChildServiceName>
    </ServiceInfo>
</ParentService>
<ParentService>
    <ParentName>Parent-7</ParentName>
    <ServiceInfo>
        <ServiceName>Service-1</ServiceName>
        <ChildServiceName>Child Service-1</ChildServiceName>
    </ServiceInfo>
</ParentService>
```

I tried this xslt. But I stucked in the begining itself.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="SecrviceRsp/Application/Parent/ParentName">           
        <ParentService>
            <ParentName>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </ParentName>
            <ServiceInfo>
                <ServiceName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="SecUserPrivQueryRsp/ApplicationInfo/ParentServiceInfo/ServiceInfo/ServiceName"/>
                </ServiceName>
            </ServiceInfo>
        </ParentService>            
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

Please guide me to complete the xslt.

Answer (score 0):

Write templates for those elements you want to transform and those templates you want to skip, then copy the rest unchanged using simply `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in XSLT 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Parent">
      <ParentService>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ParentService>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Service">
      <ServiceInfo>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ServiceInfo>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SecrviceRsp | Application | ChildService">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ApplicationName"/>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsD

or by spelling out the identity transformation template in XSLT 1 or 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Parent">
      <ParentService>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ParentService>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Service">
      <ServiceInfo>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </ServiceInfo>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SecrviceRsp | Application | ChildService">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ApplicationName"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKvF

Comment: Thanks, Martin Honnen. I am using XSLT -1 It's perfect, but if I want to change the tag names how do I do?

Comment: The suggested code does change some names e.g. `Service` is changed to `ServiceInfo` with one of the templates. If you need further changes then follow that approach, that is if you want to change e.g. `ChildServiceName` to `Child-Service-Name` then add a template `<xsl:template match="ChildServiceName"><Child-Service-Name><xsl:apply-templates/></Child-Service-Name></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin Honnen. Well explained!